# Filtering more categories out of XML item

Tags: php, xml

I would like to only get the news that has the child `<category>Lifestyle</category>` in it. But my code currently only gets the first category and I would like to have the code to search for all `<category>` in one `<item>` I have written this code in PHP so far:

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://www.nu.nl/rss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
    $category = $xml->channel->item[$i]->category;

    if(strpos($category, 'Binnenland')!==false) {   
    $html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
    $html .= "$description";
    $html .= "<br />$pubDate & $category<hr />";
    }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Some `<item>` have more categories but it should be in my filtered news as well if it contains `<category >Lifestyle</category>` (but my code currently only finds the first one)

Part of the XML:

```
  <item>
     <title>Elsevier lijft Newsflo in</title>
     <link>http://www.nu.nl/beurs/3970862/elsevier-lijft-newsflo-in.html</link>
     <description>Elsevier neemt het Britse Newsflo over. Dat maakt het bedrijf maandag bekend.</description>
     <pubDate>Mon, 12 Jan 2015 11:43:41 +0100</pubDate>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">3970862</guid>
     <enclosure url="http://media.nu.nl/m/m1mxod5a5wxc_sqr256.jpg/elsevier-lijft-newsflo-in.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpeg" />
     <category>Beurs</category>
     <dc:creator>ANP</dc:creator>
     <dc:rights>copyright photo: ANP</dc:rights>
     <atom:link href="http://nu.nl/beurs/3800685/elsevier-koopt-medische-informatieleverancier.html" type="text/html" rel="related" title="Elsevier koopt medische informatieleverancier" />
  </item>
  <item>
     <title>'Frida Giannini krijgt geen afscheidsshow bij Gucci'</title>
     <link>http://www.nu.nl/lifestyle/3970858/frida-giannini-krijgt-geen-afscheidsshow-bij-gucci.html</link>
     <description>Frida Giannini, voormalig hoofdontwerpster van Gucci, heeft geen grote afscheidsshow gekregen zoals verwacht. De ontwerpster zou vrijdag stilletjes vertrokken zijn bij het label.</description>
     <pubDate>Mon, 12 Jan 2015 11:41:52 +0100</pubDate>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">3970858</guid>
     <enclosure url="http://media.nu.nl/m/m1mxn43acqev_sqr256.jpg/frida-giannini-krijgt-geen-afscheidsshow-bij-gucci.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpeg" />
     <category>Lifestyle</category>
     <dc:creator>NU.nl</dc:creator>
     <dc:rights>copyright photo: Wenn</dc:rights>
     <atom:link href="http://nu.nl/lifestyle/3970265/alessandro-michele-nieuwe-hoofdontwerper-gucci.html" type="text/html" rel="related" title="'Alessandro Michele nieuwe hoofdontwerper Gucci'" />
     <atom:link href="http://nu.nl/lifestyle/3951514/hoofdontwerpster-en-directeur-vertrekken-bij-gucci.html" type="text/html" rel="related" title="Hoofdontwerpster en directeur vertrekken bij Gucci" />
     <atom:link href="http://nu.nl/lifestyle/3783917/hoofdontwerpster-gucci-spreekt-geruchten-vertrek.html" type="text/html" rel="related" title="Hoofdontwerpster Gucci spreekt geruchten vertrek tegen" />
  </item>
  <item>
     <title>Militairen met buitenlandse partner naar rechter</title>
     <link>http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/3970856/militairen-met-buitenlandse-partner-rechter.html</link>
     <description>Een aantal militairen met een buitenlandse partner stapt naar de rechter omdat zij al maanden geschorst thuis zitten. De schorsing is het gevolg van het feit dat hun partner niet gescreend kan worden.</description>
     <pubDate>Mon, 12 Jan 2015 11:41:24 +0100</pubDate>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">3970856</guid>
     <enclosure url="http://media.nu.nl/m/m1oxcv7anu4p_sqr256.jpg/militairen-met-buitenlandse-partner-rechter.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpeg" />
     <category>Binnenland</category>
     <category>Lifestyle</category>
     <dc:creator>ANP</dc:creator>
     <dc:rights>copyright photo: ANP</dc:rights>
  </item>
```

I think I made a mistake in the PHP but I do not know how to work around it...

Answer (score 0):

Select only desired `<item>`s with `xpath()`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$items = $xml->xpath("//item[category='Lifestyle']");
```

`//item` will select all item nodes, regardless of their position in the tree, the condition is in `[]`, `$item` is an array containing `SimpleXML` Elements.

Output:

```
foreach ($items as $item) echo $item->title . PHP_EOL;
```

see it working: https://eval.in/241693